# Custom Onclick Javascript button query

Tags: apex, javascript, webservices, onclick

Today we got a notification from Salesforce to remove scripts from home page components and put them in Visualforce areas.

Eventhough we are not impacted by this specific notification, I am just curious to know whether calling a webservice method from a custom javascript button on standard page layouts will be impacted in the near future.

Calling a webservice from a custom button is critical to our integration process and we use a similar notation like below to call the underlying webservice from our custom button on the standard page layout.

```
 sforce.apex.execute(';SearchOutboundEscalations';,';CreateOutBoundEscalation';, {SId:cId});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(#safeharbor) From the documentation I've read of late, the only change they've made is to set `REQUIRESCRIPT` tags to not execute until they're needed, which eliminates one of the loopholes we've been able to use to do things when a standard page loads.

However, there's been no announced changes saying that they're going to remove our ability to call `sforce.apex.execute` on a button click, or that we're eventually going to lose our [AJAX Proxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_proxy.htm). We should be able to use either method to perform our callouts for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, they won't impact your implementations in near future. But as you might already know, these buttons (Custom JS) don't work in SF1 app and I am not sure about Lightning Experience future roadmap.

But as you are just using SFORCE JS SDK to calling you web-service method and making an API call, IMO SF wont stop supporting this.